# how to show multiple grid on one Page in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multiple-tables

I want to show multiple grids on one report using angular js. i use one drop down look up , and with that selection i need to populate all the grids. i have two problems.
1. my drop down list isn't population anything
2. i don't seem to know how to pass to the other grids, the ID of the drop down if the drop down menu works
here is my  code

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.ctrls')
    .controller('Ctrl_Maps', function ($scope, $http) {

        //Get Item List
        $http.get('http://webapi......')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.items = data.Data;
                $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
            });
        $scope.itemChanged = function () {
            CountryGEOGrid();
        };


        function CountryGEOGrid(){

            $http.get('http://webapi......'  )
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.countryGEOs = data.Data;
                });
        }
    });
angular.module('myApp.ctrls')
    .controller('Ctrl_ActualIssueByRegion', function($scope, reportService) {
        $scope.ActualIssueByRegionGridOptions = {
            dataSource: {
                type: "jsonp",
                schema: {
                    total: function (response) {
                        return ($scope.data) ? $scope.data.TotalRows : 0;
                    }
                },
                transport: {
                    read: function(e) {
                        reportService.WebAPI('xxxx', {
                            Page:  e.data.page || 1,
                            PageSize: e.data.pageSize,
                            OrderBy: getOrderBy(e.data.sort)
                            **ItemID:selectedItem.I**temID //here i pass the ItemID
                        }).then(function (d) {
                            $scope.data = d;
                            e.success(d.Data);
                        });
                    }
                },
                serverPaging: false,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                pageSize: GLOBAL_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,
                pageSizes: GLOBAL_PAGE_SIZES
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "RowNumber"
                    ,title: "No."
                    ,width: "60px"
                },
               ......
                }
            ]
        };
    });
```

help please? am on deadline :(

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle replicating your issue ?

Comment: you redefine module `myApp.ctrls`, so just remove `;
angular.module('myApp.ctrls')` and all should work

Comment: @Grundy That's not a redefinition, that's using what he declared previously.

Comment: @OmriAharon possibly :-) but methinks that loaded data will display after loading, OP need use something like `$timeout`

Comment: Missing comma after `OrderBy: getOrderBy(e.data.sort)`

Comment: its not missing any commas :) i neglected to add that wehn posting here. i wanted to know if the way i am getting my items list from the webapi link is correct tho? thanks

Comment: @grundy avoid timeouts, especially with async calls. Use a service and promise objects and broadcast that results have come in, then retrieve those results from the service.